# How can I get an element to stay within the browser's window width when its content is wider?

Tags: html, css, page-layout

I am trying to get a div to expand to fill its container without causing that container to expand beyond the browser window's width, as in [this page](http://martincarney.com/stack-exchange/table-width/). Click "Expand" next to "Stack Trace in the last entry.

What it's supposed to do is show a horizontal scrollbar.

What it's actually doing is expanding beyond the width of the window.

I can get it to sort of work if I give the `<div class="stack">` element a `max-width` in pixels, but I want it to expand to fill no matter how wide the window is, without expanding beyond it.

How can I fix this layout? What's a general way with css to get an element to expand horizontally to fill its container while not going beyond the window's edge?

Comment: Could not access your page. Please add your relevant code into your question itself so that we might try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround solution I came up with was adding a `max-width` to the expand/collapse div. It doesn't *really* prevent the table being wider than the window, but it solves 95% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The Page is back on now!

I cann't get your table stuff sorted. There are some invalid width Parameters.
You should use div-Containers rather then tables to layout your page!

Comment: I'm modifying (or, more accurately, hacking) dotProject for my company's internal use, so completely rewriting the layout isn't going to fly.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use tables, use DIV's and for full width use

```css
width: 100%;
```

This will always use up 100% of the browser window width.

Comment: "full width use" isn't the problem. The div isn't too narrow and failing to take up the window's or container's width. It's too wide; it is forcing its container to go beyond the window's edge. Could you improve or expand your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can provide you `outer Div` `width:100%` so it will take `browser width`. Or else you can calculate browser width with `Jquery` `$(document).width();` and store this in `variable` and provide to your outer div.

Comment: Your div answer is not clear and simply wrapping the whole page or the bottom half in a `<div style="width: 100%;">` doesn't do the trick. Your jquery answer isn't relevant since I'm looking for a css solution.

Comment: See when you apply `width:100%` to `outer Div` it will expand till browser end point and after that whatever you will add it may be DIV or something else apply them display property and give width in `percentage` it will automatically wrap inside that DIV. But don't use table or `fixed width` if your window/document viewport size is less then it will go behind it.